# Way to create a function regarding JSON, and array for changing the Text value of an element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this example `JSON`

```
data = JSON.parse(dataLang);
//which produces this
{
    "Scientific Name1a":"Normal Name1",
    "Scientific Name2a":"Normal Name2",
    "Scientific Name3a":"Normal Name3",
    "Scientific Name4a":"Normal Name4",
}

or
{
    "Locality Names1":"Normal Name1",
    "Local Name2":"Normal Name2",
    "Local Name3":"Normal Name3",
}
```

**Or** Depends on the `selected value` of the user depending whether `Scientific` or `Local Name`.

After that I'm confused on how I will implement changing the `Name of an element,Context Menu,etc`..

**Is there any way to implement a function that will process the pass words, for example**

**Scenario A**

```
CallFunction(["Normal Name1,Normal Name2"]);

function CallFunction(collection){
//How to implement
return ["Scientific Name1a,Scientific Name2a"]
}
```

**Scenario B**

```
CallFunction("Local Name2");

function CallFunction(collection){
return "Normal Name2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an array of separate strings to `CallFunction`, not a single string.

```
CallFunction(["Normal Name1", "Normal Name2"]);
```

Then the function can loop through `data` and return the keys that have matching values.

```
function CallFunction(collection) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (collection.indexOf(data[key]) != -1) {
            result.push(key);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will return an array like `[Scientific Name1a", "Scientific Name2a"]`. As with the input, each string is a separate array element in the result, not combined into one element; if you want to combine them into a single string, you can use `.join()` after the function returns.

It would be more efficent if you inverted your `data` array.

```
var dataByNormal = {};
for (var scientific in data) {
    dataByNormal[data[scientific]] = scientific;
}
```

Then `CallFunction` could be written as:

```
function CallFunction(collection) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i] in dataByNormal) {
            result.push(dataByNormal[collection[i]]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want `CallFunction` to be able to take either an array or a single string, it can check the type of the argument first.

```
function CallFunction(collection) {
    if (typeof collection == "string") {
        // If we're called with a single string, treat it like a 1-element array
        collection = [collection];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a single string?

Comment: Yes. You could use `string.split(',')` to split it into an array. But in your question, you had both an array **and** a comma-separated string. One of those is not right.

Comment: If you want to pass a single string, why would you put it into an array.

Comment: because it depends on whether the translated words are collection of words which are in array or a single word/string

Comment: just like in my scenario B

Comment: Just implement it consistently. If you have a single string, wrap it in an array, `CallFunction(["Normal name"])`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much :) btw regarding the running time of your function? is it good to call your function for example 100x all at the same time?

Comment: If you're going to call it with large `collection` arrays, it would be a good idea to convert the collection to an object, because key lookups are hashed instead of needing to search.

Comment: Or if `data` is large, you could invert it into another object where the normal names are the keys.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, I'm just curious on what will be the function look like if I call the function like CallFunction("Normal Name1"); ? I'll really appreciate it. Thank you so much

Comment: Added that to the answer. It's really simple, any competent programmer should be able to figure it out.